# Map from a normed space to its double dual.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space. Let the function $J:X \rightarrow X'' $ be defined by 
$$J(x)(x')=x'(x)\ \forall\ x'\in X' $$

where $X''=\{f:X'\rightarrow\mathbb{C} \mid \hbox{$f$ is bounded linear}  \}$ and $X'$ is the dual of $X$.

Is $J$ injective?

I was trying this,

Suppose we have $x,y\in X $such that 
$$J(x)=J(y)$$
$$\Rightarrow  J(x)(x')=J(y)(x') $$
$$\Rightarrow x'(x)=x'(y)$$
$$\Rightarrow x'(x-y)=0$$
But to get $x=y $ we must have $x'$ to be injective.
I am stuck here. Is this the correct way to go about it?

Comment: Note that you have the relation $x'(x-y)=0$ for all $x'\in X'$.

Comment: It's important to see that this function is well-defined, and so you can see its linearity and injectivety.

Comment: Maybe I presume too much, but before tackling this sort of question, it could be a good idea to review basic facts about linear algebra, like "a linear function is injective iff its kernel is trivial".

Comment: @Najib I think both the criterias are equivalent.

Comment: Yes of course, but my point is that it's needlessly complicated to take two elements $x$, $y$ st $J(x) = J(y)$, then re-arranging as $J(x-y) = 0$ and eventually proving the kernel is trivial anyway, then $x-y \in \ker J \implies x=y$. Simply start with $J(x) = 0$ and prove $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping $J$ defined as above is always injective. And it is onto only if the space $X$ is reflexive (this is the definition for reflexive Banach space actually). That from $x'(x-y)=0\Rightarrow x=y$ is because the dual space is a total set and it follows from Hahn-Banach Theorem.

The corollary is:

If $x\in X\,\,$ and $x'(x)=0,\quad\forall x'\in X'$ then $x=0$

Comment: OK. I didn't know that corollary.

Comment: You should know it. There are several more, very important corollaries, that are worth knowing :)

Comment: This corollary is like alternative to the case in Hilbert spaces: if $(x,y)=0,\forall x\in H$-Hilbert space, then $y=0$

Answer (score 6):

Please pay attention: you end up with the statement

> $x'(x-y)=0$ for all $x' \in X'$.

This implies $x-y=0$, as a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem.